# How can I tell whether a given file is being used on my site?

Tags: cms, file-manager

I'm administering a site that uses a CMS, and the only access I have to the filesystem is through [ajaxplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/). I'd like to remove pictures, documents, etc. that aren't being used or linked to. Is there a way to tell what files on the site are being used, other than scraping the site and manually comparing file lists?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor any specific files or file types? Files within your root web server folder or files outside the root folder?

Comment: I want to remove any files that aren't being used or linked to. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: Just thinking aloud... If there was a tool that could compare the raw access.log with the actual file system then you could perhaps get a list of files that had not been requested during a period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way of knowing which files are linked to or being used with ajaxplorer. Images could be linked to within a style sheet ie; `background:url('image.png');` Or inserted with AJAX, jQuery, PHP or some other client side or server side language.

Xenu link sleuth is a quick way to gather all file URL's on a site, you can then export to TBS/CSV and open it in excel to see the list and sort by file type. http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

You'd then have to compare files.

I would ask for FTP access it would make your job a lot easier administering the server and keeping it clean.

Comment: Unfortunately, FTP access is not possible - the site is hosted elsewhere and they manage it. Thanks for the link to [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). It does what I need.